# SharePoint Retention Policy Workflow Association breaking in libraries

Tags: workflow, retention

I'm implementing the following solution in SharePoint 2016 (on-prem).

- Document based Content Type called "Contract" (for argument's sake)
- The Contract Content Type contains a few date based columns and the customer wants to receive notification emails when these dates are reached
- I've created a Retention Policy on the Content Type and then added various stages to that policy, each of which trigger a (SharePoint Designer created) custom workflow to send out the emails
- The Workflows are created using the SharePoint 2010 model, as required to work with Retention policies, and are Globally Published
- The Content Type is then leveraged in multiple subsites and libraries throughout that single site collection

All of that is working (after a lot of headaches) but there is one issue that remains which I think may be a bug (or otherwise just a massive annoyance).

If we update one of the Workflows in SharePoint Designer, and then Publish, the following happens:

- The new version of the Workflow is automatically applied to the Content Type. The previous version is still visible but is archived, and renamed to include the date it was created. This is fine and expected.
- The Retention Policy continues to use the previous version of the Workflow. This is fine. We just need to remember to update the Retention Policy when we update the Workflow.
- However, when we change the Retention Policy to use the new version of the Workflow, this breaks the Retention Policy everywhere it is being used. If you click on "Compliance Details" for any document based on the "Contract" content type, you will see the message "Invalid retention stage defined". This causes the workflow not to be triggered - i.e. broken.
- The only way I've found to fix this is to go to the Workflow Settings for the Site Content Type and click the option to "Update all related content types with these workflow association settings.".
- The trouble is this then creates duplicate Workflows with the same name at the child site/library level. The only solution I've found to this is to delete all the relevant workflow associations in each library before pushing the changes down.
- Given that these are now seen as new Workflows to the library, a new Workflow Status column gets added to the default View.

This all means that every time we update the Workflow in SharePoint Designer, in order for that change to take effect in the Retention Policy, we have to delete all of the previous Workflows, **everywhere they are being used**, before pushing down from the top-level site again. And that will leave us with cluttered "Views" with multiple same-named Workflow status columns. This is not a nice solution.

What I believe to be a bug is that when you modify the Retention Policy to use the new updated workflow, this should not result in the "Invalid retention stage defined" issue and thus break the policy everywhere it is being used.

If I've got something wrong I will be very glad to hear about it. I'll log this issue with MS also and see what they say.

Thanks.